# Set filter value conditionally using radio button and input search in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-table

```
export const DefaultColumnFilter11 = ({
  column: {
    filterValue,
    setFilter,
    preFilteredRows: { length },
  },
}) => {
  const [condVal, setcondVal] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value=">"
        name="cond"
        onChange={(event) => setcondVal(event.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      &lt;
      <br />
      <input
        type="radio"
        value="<"
        name="cond"
        onChange={(event) => setcondVal(event.target.value)}
      />
      &gt;
      <br />
      <Input
        value={filterValue|| ""}
        
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilter( {condVal} && (e.target.value || undefined));
        }}
        placeholder={`${length}`}
      />
      
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the code and I want to filter the column using radio button condition greater than ">" and less than "<" that should be applied to the input search.
Essentially I have some data that I would like to filter using radio buttons.
Selecting a button of a particular value should only cause those objects with that value as their property to be rendered.